# Issues with Caret predict function when using caretStack object

Tags: r, r-caret, ensemble-learning

I have been using the caretEnsemble and caret packages for stacking. My data is a document term matrix with some additional features like POS tags and the goal is performing sentiment analysis with two classes. "Sentitr" denotes the vector of sentiment corresponding to the training observations. "Sentitest" the vector for the test set.
I use a 60:40 split

```
control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10, savePredictions = "final",  classProbs = TRUE,
                        summaryFunction = twoClassSummary,
                        index=createResample(sentitr, 10))


algorithmList <- c('pda', 'nnet', 'gbm', 'svmLinear', 'rf', 'C5.0', 'glmnet')



models <- caretList(trainset, sentitr, trControl=control, methodList=algorithmList)


# some model info
summary(models)
res = resamples(models)
summary(res)
modelCor(res)
# lda and nnet extremely closely correlated



stackcontrol <- trainControl(method="cv", number=5, savePredictions = "final",  classProbs = TRUE,
                        summaryFunction = twoClassSummary)

# stacks

stack.c5.0 <- caretStack(models, method="C5.0", metric="ROC", trControl=stackcontrol)
summary(stack.c5.0)

stack.c50.pred = predict(stack.c5.0, newdata = testset, type = "raw")
stackc50.conf = confusionMatrix(stack.c50.pred, sentitest)
```

I tried to run the model 10 times every time randomly partitioning my data into a 60/40 training/test set. I received the following classification accuracies on the test set (which I extracted from the confusion matrix)

```
   X0.3225 
1   0.3225  
2   0.2550  
3   0.7500 
4   0.2675 
5   0.2950 
6   0.7825 
7   0.2575  
8   0.2875  
9   0.2900  
10  0.3275
```

These are the outputs. As you can see an accuracy of around 75-80% is achieved on two model iterations. This is expected and mirrors the results that I get from fitting single models. But the remaining iterations it yields extremely bad accuracy. It almost seems to me that the model randomly confuses testing error with accuracy. 
Any ideas what causes this behaviour

Every iteration when the prediction comes up with such terrible accuracy, I get the following error when training the caretStack:

```
2: In predict.C5.0(modelFit, newdata, trial = submodels$trials[j]) :
  'trials' should be <= 9 for this object. Predictions generated using 9 trials
3: In predict.C5.0(modelFit, newdata, type = "prob", trials = submodels$trials[j]) :
  'trials' should be <= 9 for this object. Predictions generated using 9 trials
4: In predict.C5.0(modelFit, newdata, trial = submodels$trials[j]) :
  'trials' should be <= 9 for this object. Predictions generated using 9 trials
5: In predict.C5.0(modelFit, newdata, type = "prob", trials = submodels$trials[j]) :
  'trials' should be <= 9 for this object. Predictions generated using 9 trials
```